# Eval expression during compilation time in Erlang

Tags: compilation, erlang, metaprogramming, constexpr

Is it possible to have some kind of `constexpr` equivalent in Erlang?

I have some expression

```
obj() -> func("some string")
```

in which `func` is a pure function (result does not depend on anything other than the arguments) and I would like it to be executed during compilation time. How can I achieve it?

EDIT I can accept any reasonable hacks, as long as they allow `func` to be a casual function

Comment: Functions cannot be executed at compile time. But compiler can recognize literals in function definitions and provide some optimisation. See http://blog.erlang.org/core-erlang-optimizations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ct_expand`](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans/blob/master/doc/ct_expand.md), part of Ulf Wiger's [`parse_trans`](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans) repository.  To use it, specify that the compiler should use `ct_expand` as a parse transform:

```
-compile({parse_transform, ct_expand}).
```

and then, for each expression you want to evaluate at compile time, wrap it in `ct_expand:term/1`:

```
obj() -> ct_expand:term(func("some string")).
```

See also [the example module](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans/blob/master/examples/ct_expand_test.erl).

Answer (score 1):

Erlang has things called [macros](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#defining-and-using-macros), which are expanded at compilation time.  Here's an example of what you can do:

a.erl:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-define(FUNC(Str), "hello "++Str).

go() ->
    ?FUNC("world").
```

In the shell:

```
4> compile:file("a.erl", ['P']).

{ok,[]}

^C^C
```

At the command line:

```
~/erlang_programs$ cat a.p
-file("a.erl", 1).

-module(a).

-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    "hello " ++ "world".
```

Comment: I see you defined FUNC as a macro - in my case func needs to be a casual erlang function